# How to fill margin space with divs and give it styles?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width

For my Website I’d like to have a banner on my header (with all things like logo, menu), which covers 100% of my screen width.

Fine and easy so far.

But now, after a certain screen resolution that banner should stop filling 100%, 
so I just gave a `max-width: 1000px;` and a `margin: 0 auto;` for centering my banner.

The Problem:

In this example, when the screen width exceeds 1000px I will get a `margin left` and `margin right` depending on screen width minus the 1000px.

I want each of that margins to have a gradient color or any other styles which other people might want to have.

For this I created a structure (below) which is missing the magic code that I don’t know about or maybe it even needs a complete different solution.

The basis of my structure / code are 3 divs aligned in one row with my banner in the center.

The point where I don’t come any further is how to give the "margins / fill ups” widths matching the remaining space.

Example structure:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
.center {
    width: 100%;
    /*below breakpoint 1000px*/

    max-width: 1000px;
    /*above breakpoint 1000px*/

    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*getting rid of the "fill ups" below breakpoint 1000px"*/

@media screen (max-width: 1000px) {
    .left {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }
    .right {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }
}
/*generating "fill ups" for remaining space between screen border and "center" (left and right)*/

@media screen (min-width: 1001px) {
    .left {
        width: 200px;
        /* width:50%; would like to have 50% of the remaining space (left)*/

        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        float: left;
    }
    .right {
        width: 200px;
        /* width:50%; would like to have 50% of the remaining space (right)*/

        height: 200px;
        background: blue;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS or jQuery for this.

Simply calculate the difference between the width of the `.center` `<div>` and the widow width, and then divide that by two to get equal ones on both sides.

**jQuery**

```
$(".left, .right").css({width: ($(window).width - $(".center").width()) / 2});
```

---

Actually, I guess you could do this with CSS's `calc()` as well, but this is slightly less dynamic because you have to input the width of the `.center` `<div>` (1000px in your case):

**CSS**

```
.left, .right {
    width: calc((100% - 1000px) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is perfect add screen and in media   [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hotureboko/edit?html,css,output)

> @media screen and(min-width: 1000px)
> {
> **It says apply style for device with a screen and a window with min-width**
>   }

```
/*getting rid of the "fill ups" below breakpoint 1000px"*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { 
    .left{
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
    }
    .right{
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
    }
}    

/*generating "fill ups" for remaining space between screen border and "center" (left and right)*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) { 
    .left {
        width:200px; /* width:50%; would like to have 50% of the remaining space (left)*/
        height:200px;
        background:red;
        float:left;
    }
    .right {
        width:200px; /* width:50%; would like to have 50% of the remaining space (right)*/
        height:200px;
        background:blue;
        float:right;
    }
}
```